# QR factorization of a 4x4 symmetric tridiagonal matrix

Tags: matrices

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & 0 & 0\\
a_{12} & a_{22} & a_{23} & 0\\
0 & a_{23} & a_{33} & a_{34} \\
0 & 0 & a_{34} & a_{44} \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
q_{11} & q_{12} & q_{13} & q_{14} \\
q_{21} & q_{22} & q_{23} & q_{24} \\
q_{31} & q_{32} & q_{33} & q_{34} \\
q_{41} & q_{42} & q_{43} & q_{44} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
r_{11} & r_{12} & r_{13} & r_{14} \\
0 & r_{22} & r_{23} & r_{24} \\
0 & 0 & r_{33} & r_{34} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & r_{44} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I am trying to solve the following problem:
For the given 4x4 symmetric tridiagonal matrix A, determine which elements of its QR factorization is zero. The trick is to determine this visually.

I plugged a simple 4x4 symmetric tridagonal matrix into MATLAB and took its qr factorization and found that the top left element, $$r_{14}$$ of the matrix R and the bottom left 3 elements, $$q_{31}, q_{41}, q_{42}$$ of the matrix Q are zero. But the task was to determine this with ease and visually. Is there a trick to do this? I am not seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show you how to obtain some zeros and you should be able to continue by yourself. Consider the first column of $R$.You have $q_{11}r_{11}=a_{11}$, $q_{21}r_{11}=a_{12}$, $q_{31}r_{11}=0$ and $q_{41}r_{11}=0$. If $a_{11}$ or $a_{12}$ is not $0$, then you have necessarely that $r_{11} \neq 0$, and so you have $q_{31}=0$ and $q_{41}=0$.You can try to do the same kind of reasoning on the following column of $R$ for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot that makes sense. One question though: if $a_{11}$ and/or $a_{12}$ is 0, is the A matrix still tridiagonal?

Comment: I think that tridiagonal means that  $a_{ij}=0$, $\forall i,j$ such as $|i-j|>1$. But in your case it is propably assume the other elements are not $0$, otherwise you could not know a lot of things visually.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm thinking. Otherwise, the solution would not be unique.

Comment: For the second column of R, I obtain \begin{equation}
q_{11}r_{12} + q_{12}r_{22} = a_{12}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
q_{21}r_{12} + q_{22}r_{22} = a_{22}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
q_{32}r_{22} = a_{23}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
q_{42}r_{22} = 0
\end{equation}    looking at the last 2 expressions, we can see that $r_{22}$ and $q_{32}$ are non-zero and $q_{42}$ is 0, but this doesn't seem to say anything about $q_{12}$ and $q_{22}$?

Comment: Yes that's it :).

Comment: But how would we know if $q_{12}$ and $q_{22}$ are non-zero? It seems this would depend on specific case we are talking about.

Comment: You can't know that, you can't have every informations about about all the elements of Q in such a general case.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. I know that $r_{14} = 0$, but this process doesn't seem to conclude that?

Comment: I don't see how to find this other result sorry.